# How can I improve the responsiveness of my touch screen controls?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch, multi-touch

Here is a small clip of my game play: https://gfycat.com/DisfiguredImpressionableGalapagossealion

The right side of the screen `(finId2)` controls the aiming and firing while the left side of the screen `(finId1)` is used to change the selected lane via swiping up and down.

As can be seen the gameplay depends on how fast the player can change lanes.

I have written a script that controls both sides of the screen but the swiping is a big sluggish and at times a swipe is missed entirely.

Is it because I am looping over all swipes way too often? Can anyone please have a look at my implementation of this and suggest how the swiping mechanism can be made more responsive?

```
int screenDivision;
int finId1 = -1;
int finId2 = -1;

bool tap, swipeUp, swipeDown;
bool isDraging = false;
Vector2 startTouch, swipeDelta;
int swipeDeadzone = 5;

void Start(){

        Input.multiTouchEnabled = true;
        screenDivision = Screen.width / 4;
        canAim = true;
        canFire = true;
    }

void Update()
    {
        tap = swipeUp = swipeDown = false;

        //update the arrow pointer rotation (which is used for shooting the arrow in a straight line w.r.t. the tower)

        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            // loop through every touch
            foreach (var touch in Input.touches)
            {
                if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                {
                    //For left half screen
                    if (touch.position.x <= screenDivision && finId1 == -1)
                    {
                        isDraging = true;
                        tap = true;
                        startTouch = touch.position;
                        finId1 = touch.fingerId;        //store the fingerId of the left touch for as long as touch has not been ended though TouchPhase.Ended
                    }
                    //For right half screen
                    else if (touch.position.x > screenDivision && finId2 == -1)
                    {

                        mouseStart = touch.position.y;

                        if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId))
                            canAim = false;


                        finId2 = touch.fingerId;
                    }
                }
                //touchPhase.Ended for the archer firing is handled in LateUpdate() so here only the left finger will be handled, target only the left finger via finId1 which was set in TouchPhase.Began
                else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Canceled)
                {
                    if (touch.fingerId == finId1)
                    {
                        //Reset or release the fingerId for next touch
                        finId1 = -1;
                        isDraging = false;
                        Reset();
                    }
                }

            }
            //below if block if for the archer firing so only looking at fingerId2 here
            if (finId2 != -1)      //touch has begun and finId2 has been assigned  
            {
                //if right tap is detected this block will set the animation state of the archer, play the bow sound and make ready to fire

            }


        }

        //Below code handles the swiping mechanism of the left side of the screen.
        swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
        if (isDraging)
        {
            foreach (var touch in Input.touches)
            {
                //looping through all touches but only care about finId1 which is used for left half of screen
                if (touch.fingerId == finId1)
                {
                    swipeDelta = touch.position - startTouch;
                }
            }
        }

        //Did we cross the deadZone?
        if (swipeDelta.magnitude > swipeDeadzone)
        {
            //which direction?
            float x = swipeDelta.x;
            float y = swipeDelta.y;
            if (Mathf.Abs(x) > Mathf.Abs(y))
            {
                // Left or Right Swipe
                //Unused in this game
            }
            else
            {
                //up or down swipe
                if (y < 0)
                {
                    swipeDown = true;
                    spawner.Rotate(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    swipeUp = true;
                    spawner.Rotate(true);
                }
            }

            Reset();
        }

    }
```

The swiping mechanism is handled entirely in the `Update()` block. Where as the final state of the arrow firing is handled in the `LateUpdate()` as done below:

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    //if the player can aim
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        if (canAim)
        {
            foreach (var touch in Input.touches)
            {
                if (touch.fingerId == finId2)
                {
                    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
                    {
                        //code to move the line renderer showing arrow line prediction.


                    }
                    else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                    {
                        zRotation = 0;
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var touch in Input.touches)
        {
            if (touch.fingerId == finId2)
            {
                if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                {
                    finId2 = -1;

                    // code that handles arrow behaviour and shoots arrow

                    //can aim again
                    canAim = true;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}


private void Reset()
{
    startTouch = swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
    isDraging = false;
}
```

I know this might not be the most elegant way to achieve what I want but, it is what I could put together from reading online documentation for multitouch.

Any guidance on how to improve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What OS are you targeting?

Comment: Android. Sorry, should have mentioned in question.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this same issue.  The problem is the OS touch input is running faster that of the game loop.   This is similar to Windows updating the Mouse 240 times per second and the game loop running at 30 or 60 frames per second.

My solution was to implement custom swipe code in `public void OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)` in the Activity.  This allows the swipes to be processed when triggered instead of across multiple game frames.

Care must be taken within the method to make it as tight as possible.

The [OnTouchEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) is Android's method to allow and Activity to handle touch events. The parameter passed in e is of type [MotionEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent)

These links are for Java, when converting the names to C# just Capitalize the first letter of the method calls, for example, e.getY() becomes e.GetY().

Place the `public void OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)` in your UnityActivity file.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I'm sorry I dont think I understand. Can you please elaborate on the method you used to fix this. To implement multi-touch I had to study and implement ``TouchPhase`` and use the different phases of each touch to detect whats going on., ``OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)`` was not mentioned in the Unity documentation for multi-touch so I don't exactly know how it is supposed to work or how to implement it in my code above? Thanks

Comment: This is not Unity3D, but it is implemented between The Xamarin C# runtime and Unity3D.